# graphql server, resolver depended on another resolver

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

assume I have schema like this

`type Result{
   fieldA: TypeA,
   fieldB: TypeB,
   # other fileds ... 
}`

fieldB is computed based on fieldA like:

```
function getData(){...}
function transformData(){...}
resolverA:()=>getData()
resolverB:()=>transformData(getData())
```

queries could ask for either/both or non of field A/B

assume both getData() and transformData() are expensive operations,

how do I write the resolvers so that :

1) resolverB use the resolved data from resolverA

2) getData only gets called once when both AB fields are in the query

3) None of getData/transformData gets called when only asking for other fields

Answer (score 2):

I would probably just memoize `getData` and be done with it. You can use [dataloader](https://github.com/facebook/dataloader) for that or write your own simple closure that resets it's data on the next tick:

```
const getData = (function () {
  let cache
  return function () {
    if (cache) return cache
    cache = // do heavy stuff

    process.nextTick(() => {
      cache = null
    })
    return cache
  }
})()
```

Comment: If we use GraphQLRootContext as cache it will soon contain everything and become dirty. If we don't use GraphQLRootContext as cache, then what should we use?